# Confusion regarding trainer.test() result

Tags: pytorch, training-data

I wanted to know if the following result is unusual. The value is negative and as far as I know, low values signify better results but just wanted to confirm.

```
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
Testing: 100%
19/19 [00:02<00:00, 9.33it/s]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATALOADER:0 TEST RESULTS
{'test_loss': -2.5980350971221924}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out[51]:
[{'test_loss': -2.5980350971221924}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are minimizing a loss, then yes... lower is better!

Absolute loss values have no meaning if you are not giving context *i.e.* the functional expression of your objective. You can make any objective function negative while ***not changing*** the behaviour of training: you just need to subtract by something big enough and your loss value will end up negative but its derivative will remain unchanged!